# Styling RSS with CSS

Tags: php, css, rss

I have a PHP script that pulls an RSS feed. The script pulls the article and sets it as a variable:

```
$page .= "<br><span class='rssdesc'>$description</span>";
```

I can change the size of images in an article with the following CSS:

```
.rssdesc img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

This works fine. However I cannot seem to style the text of the article. I assumed this would be accomplished like this:

```
.rssdesc {
font-size:9px;
color: #0094DE;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn’t work. I have tried using *!important* and *.rssdesc font*
but still nothing. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

*Update* I can also style links in an article using the following:

```
.rssdesc a:link {
color: #0094DE;
font-size:9px;
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: RSS styling is tricky, mainly because not all readers support all kinds of CSS. Some support it like a browser, others render it as plaintext, or use MS Word as render engine. Some restrict the use of some CSS to keep text visible and readable.

Comment: May be it's inheriting default properties. Check whether you assigned any css property for `span` tag.

Comment: Check this link : http://www.petefreitag.com/item/208.cfm

Comment: I just noticed I can change the font-family, but not the size or colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the tables in the RSS feed was responsible setting the font properties. I was able to override this in the CSS using the following:

```
.rssdesc table td {
 color: #c02537;
 font-size:9px;
 }
```